# Computing an integral via the Cauchy integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to compute the following integral

$$ \int_{|z|=2 } \frac{z^3}{(z+1)^3} dz$$

using the Cauchy Integral formula. The issue is that I do not see how to rewrite the integrand so that the theorem is applicable. I tried

$$ \frac{z^3}{(z+1)^3}= \frac{f(z)}{z-z_1}, \ \text{where} \ f(z)=\frac{z^3}{(z+1)^2} \ \text{and} \ z_1=-1$$

but then the issue is that f is not holomorphic on the disk of radius 2 over which I need to integrate. What else can I do to rewrite the integrand?

Comment: Now apply Cauchy-Goursat.  [Example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula#Example).

Answer (score 1):

Pick $\varepsilon > 0$ small enough so that $D_1 = \{z \in \mathbb C: |z + 1| < \varepsilon\} \subseteq \{z \in \mathbb C: |z| < 2\} = D_2$, possible since the latter set is open and contains $-1$.

Note that the integrand is analytic in $D_2 \setminus D_1$, and that the boundaries of the regions $D_1, D_2$ are simple closed curves. (they are the circles $|z + 1| = \varepsilon$ and $|z| = 2$)

So by the deformation theorem (see, say http://ftp.xecu.net/jacobs/vCalc/Complex/deform.pdf):

$$\int_{|z| = 2} \frac {z^3} {(z + 1)^3} \mathrm dz = \int_{|z + 1| = \varepsilon} \frac {z^3} {(z + 1)^3} \mathrm dz$$

The latter integral should yield immediately to Cauchy's integral formula.

Comment: But if I try to apply Cauchy's integral formula to the latter integral I get (using my choice of f from my initial comment above) $\int_{|z + 1| = \varepsilon} \frac {z^3} {(z + 1)^3} \mathrm dz=2 \pi i \cdot f(-1)=2 \pi i \frac{z^3}{(-1-(-1))^2}=2 \pi i \frac{z^3}{(-1+1)^2}$ which is not defined (unless I'm missing something). So unfortunately I don't see how this helps.

Comment: Consider the second derivative of an appropriate function instead!

Note: $$f^{(n)}(a) = \frac {n!} {2 \pi i} \int_{|z - a| = r} \frac {f(z)} {(z - a)^{n + 1}} \mathrm dz$$